# Can the product of logistic ($x_1$) and logistic ($x_2$) be approximated by logistic ($x_1+x_2$)?

Tags: logistic-regression

Consider two logistic functions that are multiplied
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{e^{x_1}}{1+e^{x_1}} \times\frac{e^{x_2}}{1+e^{x_2}}=\frac{e^{x_1+x_2}}{1+e^{x_1+x_2}+e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}
$$

To what extent (or under which non-trivial conditions) can this be approximated by
$$
f(x_1,x_2) \approx \frac{e^{x_1+x_2}}{1+e^{x_1+x_2 }}
$$
?

Comment: You can calculate the error of the approximation explicitly by calculating $r(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1,x_2) - \exp(x_1+x_2)/(1+\exp(x_1+x_2))$.

Comment: This is quite useful.  I will do some simulations.  Thanks!

Comment: When $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both positive (and are large enough), $e^{x_1 + x_2}$ will be much larger than $e^{x_1}$ or $e^{x_2}$, so we can disregard the latter terms. Similarly, when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both negative (and large enough in absolute value), $1$ will be much larger than $e^{x_1}$ or $e^{x_2}$, so we can disregard the latter terms.

Comment: I understand the point when they are both positive and large, but not why it would be the case if they are negative and large.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

If $x_1 = z$ and $x_2 = -z$, then it most definitely is not a logistic-shaped curve (it would be bell-shaped). So in that case, it cannot be approximated by such a function.